# OCR for Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opencv, ocr

I am a beginner. I wants to implement App the Business Card Reader(OCR), I have little knowledge of OpenCV. I wants to know from where I start? any links or example really appreciated.

I already try this https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo/tree/master/OCRDemo but in this source code accuracy is not good.

So I personally decide to increase the quality of images by using openCV, Like I am changing Orignal Image to GRAY image and then in BLack and White, But still output of OCR is not good. I have to increase the quality of characters in image so my OCR Reader reads Character easily for best accuracy.

I am regularly trying to achieving the best accuracy, But still not getting anything :(

Thanks All

Comment: our friendly site, google.com

Comment: @pro_metedor not need project manager, Please check the edited Question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find your question answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone

If you need any help working with them, let us know and we can help you.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, OCR  is  fuzzy thema.  There is a lot of approaches -  like tesseract / open CV etc.  But basically it boils down to:

- get image
- find ROI
- preprocess
- binarise
- locate glyphs
- recognize them
- enhance quality with additional knowlege

AFAIR tesseract and openCF try to analyse  character shapes and contures, and are best suited for big amounts of texts, so they can apply dictionaries to augment recognition.   I got good results with  invariant moments and clusterr analysis -  it is fast enough to be used offline,  and offers good  recognition results for defined fonts ( I got 99.96% on defined font samples )

Unfortunately for you,  this library is in java, and not usable on iOS directly ( but on android ):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

But you may choose to port some techniques  - like adaptive binarisation ( sauvola algorythm )  invariant moment extraction and cluster matching